# SQL Row array field can be reached with integer index but not with string index

Tags: mysql, php

I'm getting error when i try to refer index with string

The error:

> Notice: Undefined index: subject_id in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP at the line 17

The code:

```
$Pages = mysql_query("select * from pages where subject_id ={$Row["subject_id"]}",$Connection);

while ($PageRow = mysql_fetch_array($Pages))
{
    echo "<li>{$PageRow["menu_name"]}</li>";
}
```

But it works fine if i use the integer index instead,

```
    echo "<li>{$Row[2]}</li>";
```

I've seen the same code in an example code and it works, is the problem with the MySQl database setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given the error as

> Notice: Undefined index: **subject_id** in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP at
>   the line 17

, so subject_id should be the problem. In the example code, you have menu_name as the key of the array. So, which one is it? What are the columns of this table? The code that you've given will work if there is a "menu_name" column in the table.

The problem should be the name of the column that you want to access. Check that again.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember - var_dump() is your best friend in this kind of situations.

Answer (score 2):

You are not fetching the result row as an associative array & although you are using curly braces I would change the quotes to single quotes just for consistency .
Change to this:

```
 $SubjectSet = mysql_query("select * from subjects" , $Connection);
 while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($SubjectSet)) // change to mysql_fetch_assoc()
 {
     echo "<li>{$Row['menu_name']}</li>"; // use single quotes
 }
```

you can check what keys & values are begin returned by using:

```
$SubjectSet = mysql_query("select * from subjects" , $Connection);
 while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($SubjectSet)) // change to mysql_fetch_assoc()
 {
     print_r($Row);
 }
```

Comment: Technically there's nothing wrong with mysql_fetch_array to fetch associative arrays - by default it should fetch an associative array with both an integer index and the field names as keys (`MYSQL_BOTH` is the default) - but if it's been set to `MYSQL_NUM` for some reason, then yes...

Comment: @Cd001 true but the error says that the index is undefined, thus above solution to force the associative array. plus mysql_fetch_assoc looks cleaner

Comment: thanx for help i did a mistake, i posted the wrong part of code previously :$ sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's the quote marks in the echo... you're using double quotes in both instances which will break the string (it *shouldn't* since you've wrapped it in curly braces, but still...).

Try:

```
echo"<li>{$Row['menu_name']}</li>";
```

If that doesn't work - ensure you're fetching an associative array from the database; you may need to pass either the the constant `MYSQL_ASSOC` or `MYSQL_BOTH` to the query (though, by default, it should use `MYSQL_BOTH`).

`$Row=mysql_fetch_array($SubjectSet, MYSQL_ASSOC)`

Comment: thanx for help i did a mistake, i posted the wrong part of code previously :$ sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using single quotes instead:

```
 $SubjectSet=mysql_query("select * from subjects",$Connection);
  while($Row=mysql_fetch_assoc($SubjectSet))
  {
    echo"<li>{$Row['menu_name']}</li>";// line 17
  }
```

**CORRECTION:**

Just noticed you didn't use assoc fetching. Use the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` method instead if you wish to access columns using their name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed?

```
$SubjectSet=mysql_query("select * from subjects",$Connection);
while($Row=mysql_fetch_array($SubjectSet)) {
    echo"<li>".$Row["menu_name"]."</li>";
}
```

Comment: The it has to be another line: "Undefined index: subject_id" There is no subject_id in this line.

Comment: `echo"<li>".{$Row["menu_name"]}."</li>";` is somewhat superfluous since you've broken the string and concatenated it anyway ... the second example (`echo"<li>".$Row["menu_name"]."</li>";
`) is better.

Comment: thanx for help i did a mistake, i posted the wrong part of code previously :$ sorry.

Answer (score 0):

:) use `MYSQL_ASSOC` with `mysql_fetch_array()` or use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead:

```
while($Row=mysql_fetch_array($SubjectSet, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

or

```
while($Row=mysql_fetch_assoc($SubjectSet))
```

You can read [this](http://deepbluespaces.blogspot.com/2008/05/difference-between-mysqlfetcharray-and.html). I tried to make this as short as possible for you!

Comment: thanx for help i did a mistake, i posted the wrong part of code previously :$ sorry.